# How to work with data returned by mysql select query in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, bots

I am working on a discord bot written in nodejs, the bot utilises a mysql database server to store information. The problem I have run into is that I cannot seem to retrieve the data from the database in a neat way, every single thing I try seems to run into some issue or another.

The select query returns an object called RowDataPacket. When googling every single result will reference this solution: Object.values(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows)))

It postulates that I should get the values back, but I dont I get an array back that is as hard to work with as the rowdatapacket object.

This is a snippet of my code:

```
const kenneledMemberRolesTableName = 'kenneled_member_roles'
const kenneledMemberKey = 'kenneled_member'
const kenneledMemberRoleKey = 'kenneled_member_role_id'
const kenneledStaffMemberKey = 'kenneled_staff_member'
const kenneledDateKey = 'kenneled_date'
const kenneledReturnableRoleKey = 'kenneled_role_can_be_returned'

async function findKenneledMemberRoles(kenneledMemberId) {
    let sql = `SELECT CAST(${kenneledMemberRoleKey} AS Char) FROM ${kenneledMemberRolesTableName} WHERE ${kenneledMemberKey} = ${kenneledMemberId}`
    let rows = await databaseAccessor.runQuery(sql)
    let result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows)).map(row => {
        return row.kenneled_member_role_id
    })
    return result
}
```

This seemed to work, until I had to do a type conversion on the value, now the dot notations requires me to reference row.CAST(kenneled_member_role_id AS Char), this cannot work, and I have found no other way to retrieve the data than through dot notation. I swear there must be a better way to work with mysql rowdatapackets but the solution eludes me

Answer (score 0):

I figured out something that works, however I still feel like this is an inelegant solution, I would love to hear from others if I am misunderstanding how to work with mysql code in nodejs, or if this is just a consequence of the library:

```
let result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows)).map(row => {
    return row[`CAST(${kenneledMemberRoleKey} AS CHAR)`];
})
```

So what I did is I access the value through brackets instead of dot notation, this seems to work, and at least makes me able to store part of or the whole expression in a constant variable, hiding the ugliness.